# How to get the result of ShowInputAsync Dialog in Mahapps

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

The `ShowInputAsync()` returns a string, but I want to get the result, I mean Affirmation or Cancellation, from the Dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it returns **null**, it means the user hit **Cancel**:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await this.ShowInputAsync("Test", "Enter string:");

        if (result == null)
            return;

        await this.ShowMessageAsync("Test", "You entered " + result + "!");
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Problem Solved! Thanks!

Comment: If user do not input anything, then click OK, it also result null.